# Using a member type of templated class as the type of a class member variable

Tags: c++, templates

Why does the following not compile (MSVC10 - but I suspect it's not valid C++), and is there a workaround?

```
template <typename M>
struct MyClass
{
    typedef std::vector<M>::iterator iteratorT;

    iteratorT myIterator;

};
```

Error is `error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iteratorT'`. I've tried a bunch of variations with the same result: you can use `std::vector<M>::iterator` as a type in a member function, but not as a type of a member variable.

Comment: A rather frequent FAQ. See here http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know what to search for to find an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a case of the `typename`. Short answer, you need to do this instead:

```
 typedef typename std::vector< M >::iterator iteratorT;
```

Long answer, the compiler doesn't know what `std::vector< M >::iterator` resolves to as `M` can be anything and there could be a specialization of `std::vector` for it. Specifically, it cannot tell if `std::vector< M >::iterator` is a type or a value, and it believes its a value. You have to explicitly tell the compiler its a type by inserting `typename`.

Comment: D'oh! Idiot moment. I'm so used to MSVC not needing `typename` that I tend to think of it as a `gcc` problem!

Comment: @Zero: Yeah, its quite unfortunate that MSVC does not implement two-phase template lookup correctly.